# Problem(Invalid File Response) in Image Upload in android

Tags: android

Hi Friends i face a problem when i upload the Image the Response come Invalid File so please help for solve this problem.

```
 public void executeMultipartPost() throws Exception {

              try {

                  ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                  MybitmapImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 75, bos);
                  byte[] data = bos.toByteArray();
                  HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                  HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost("http://myurl.net/uploadphoto.aspx");
                  ByteArrayBody bab = new ByteArrayBody(data,"5.png");

             //     File file= new File("/sdcard/mickey.jpg");

              //     FileBody bin = new FileBody(file,"image/jpg");

                  MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
                //  reqEntity.addPart("5.jpg",bin);

                  reqEntity.addPart("5.png", bab);



                  postRequest.setEntity(reqEntity);
                  System.out.println("Method"+postRequest.getMethod());
                  System.out.println("tostring"+postRequest.toString());

                  HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postRequest);

                  BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
                  String sResponse;
                  StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
                  while ((sResponse = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                      s = s.append(sResponse);
                  }

                  System.out.println("Response: " + s);

              } catch (Exception e) {

                  // handle exception here
                  System.out.println("Error"+e);
                  Log.e(e.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage());

              }

          }
```

In Response Invalid Flie Comes. so plase try to solve my problem.
Thanks a lot

Comment: Please add the stack trace and error messages to the question.

Comment: There are no Error is come but In Response is like this: 08-16 13:02:06.345: INFO/System.out(661): Response: Invalid File

Comment: can u upload image to ur webserver?

Answer (score 0):

To add an image, try something like (the code you have commented)-

```
File fileToUpload = new File(filePath);
FileBody fileBody = new FileBody(fileToUpload, "image/jpeg");
reqEntity.addPart("file", fileBody);
```

instead of adding `ByteArrayBody`.

Answer (score 0):

To log your error, try in your `catch`

```
catch (Exception e) {

     // handle exception here
     e.printStackTrace();

}
```